# What is "kinematic inversion" (from geophysics) in mathematical terms?

Tags: kinematics, terminology, geophysics

I am a mathematician working on a seismic imaging problem, and am currently (attempting to) read some geophysics papers ([this one](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/233898393_Determination_of_the_friction_law_parameters_of_the_Mw_6.7_Michilla_earthquake_in_northern_Chile_by_dynamic_inversion) (Ruiz, Madariaga 2011) and [this one](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2009JB006358/abstract) (Di Carli, Francois-Holden, Peyrat, Madariaga 2009)) to see if their techniques are applicable to (or make redundant) the methods I'm trying to develop.

In particular, both of these papers reference a "kinematic inversion" of the seismic data without further discussion of what exactly this entails.

Thus, I would be grateful for any brief explanations of this process, and/or good references on the subject. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning : I absolutely don't know nothing about the subject.

If you are a french locutor, applyed notion of kinematical inversion (and dynamical inversion) to the  Tottori
 earthquake are explained in this  [thesis (Sara Di Carli)](http://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/32/53/09/PDF/These-DiCarli-TEL.pdf),  see page $4$ for a abstract, and pages $11-29$ for details.

The [Haskell Model(1964)](http://www.bssaonline.org/content/54/1/377.abstract) seems to be the first model.

In the thesis, the references $(12)$ to $(25)$ (at the end of the paper) seem to correspond to kinematical inversion papers (see page $4$).

I found your [english reference](http://www.seg2.ethz.ch/dalguer/courses/earthquake/dicarli_etal2010jgr.pdf) too in free access